# Converting from RedShift to MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I am using this code currently in Redshift where it works completely fine.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(ld1.package_route,'(Sorted|Xdocked)->.{1,8}->|->(Sorted|Xdocked)->.{1,8}$','') AS short_package_route
```

I want to implement this code in MySQL as well.(I am using MYSQL Workbench 6.3) but the Regex_Replace function is not supported.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free conversion (coding) service or a excuse into not having to research digg in the RDMS manuals..

Comment: Actually, MySQL 8+ _does_ have a `REGEXP_REPLACE` function, whose syntax is probably very similar to what you are using now.  If you have a long term need for regex support, then consider upgrading (and besides, your current MySQL version will be twilighted pretty soon anyway).

Comment: i wonder @TimBiegeleisen if the regex engine is really needed in this case ... a nested `REPLACE()` to replace `Sorted` and `Xdocked` to '' seams to be also fine here ... Also `(Sorted|Xdocked)->.{1,8}->|->(Sorted|Xdocked)->.{1,8}$` seams to a repeating regex which does the same thing twice ...